# Creating a program to establish connection to PLC through PVI and another program

Tags: c#, automation

As the title says I need help **writing a program that will connect to PVI and another program**(*I am not sure if it is possible to establish communication with a program like this that was written by the original machine manufacturer I will provide as much detail as i can if needed on this.*) this will then **exchange information from the PLC to the program running and allow freezing the frame of this program and taking screenshots of it as well as unfreezing it after**.

I will include the code that i have so far which I wrote using a training manual provided from B&R this is just to establish connection to PVI and the automation studio program running on a PLC.

This is an outdated training manual but is the only source of information I have available for this problem. **The program i wrote does compile and run it does seem to make something of a connection to a PLC that I have connected to my laptop as well as when running the simulation program without a PLC. However it does not read data from the program as the training manual explains it would read the values of some variables i have made in automation studio.**

Also when attempting to click on any of the buttons i made and i will be honest i am not 100% sure what they are even supposed to do it will give me an error `(System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' myStructPV was null.)`.
Which i assume is trying to tell me that the variable that is being used when the button is pushed is null however these variables are part of the PVI services namespace and i am not sure what value you would give them in initialization.

I do apologize if this does not make much sense as i mentioned i am quite new at developing and have not used Visual studio or C# since college way back.

Any advice or help will be appreciated very much thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using BR.AN.PviServices;

namespace PVITestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Service myService;
        public Cpu myCpu;
        public BR.AN.PviServices.Task myTask;
        public Variable myVariable;
        public Module myModule;
        public Variable myVariablePV1;
        public Variable myStructPV;

        public Form1()
        {


            InitializeComponent();
            // txtStatus.Text = "text box is functioning!";


        }

        private void MyStructPV_Error(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void MyStructPV_ValueChanged(object sender, VariableEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myService = new Service("service");
            myService.Connected += MyService_Connected;
            myService.IsStatic = true;
            myService.Connect();
        }

        private void MyService_Connected(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtStatus.Text += "Service Connected\r\n";
            if (myCpu == null)
            {
                myCpu = new Cpu(myService, "cpu");
                //myCpu.Connection.DeviceType = BR.AN.PviServices.DeviceType.TcpIp;
                myCpu.Connection.DeviceType = DeviceType.TcpIp;
                myCpu.Connection.TcpIp.DestinationStation = 2;
                myCpu.Connection.TcpIp.DestinationPort = 11160;
                myCpu.Connection.TcpIp.DestinationIpAddress = "192.168.0.1";

                //myCpu.Connection.TcpIp.DestinationIpAddress = "127.0.0.1";
                myCpu.Connected += MyCpu_Connected;
                myCpu.Error += MyCpu_Error;
                myCpu.Connect(ConnectionType.CreateAndLink);
                // maybe need to use this one - myCpu.Connect(ConnectionType.Create);
            }

           // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        private void MyCpu_Error(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtStatus.Text += e.Name + " Error:" + e.ErrorCode + "\r\n";
           // throw new NotImplementedException(txtStatus.Text = "Error connecting.");
        }

        private void MyCpu_Connected(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtStatus.Text += "CPU Connected\r\n";
            myTask = new BR.AN.PviServices.Task(myCpu, "pvitest");
            myTask.Connected += MyTask_Connected;
            myTask.Error += MyTask_Error;
            myTask.Connect();
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void MyTask_Error(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtStatus.Text += e.Name + " Error:" + e.ErrorCode + "\r\n";
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void MyTask_Connected(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtStatus.Text += "Task " + e.Name + " Connected\r\n";
            if (myVariable == null)
            {
                myVariable = new Variable(myTask, "Lifesign");
                myVariable.Active = true;
                myVariable.RefreshTime = 200;
                myVariable.ValueChanged += MyVariable_ValueChanged;
                myVariable.Error += MyVariable_Error;
                myVariable.Connect();
            }
            if (myVariablePV1 == null)
            {
                myVariablePV1 = new Variable(myTask, "VarCreateOnly");
                myVariablePV1.Address = "PV1";
                myVariablePV1.Connect(ConnectionType.Create);
            }
           // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void MyVariable_Error(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            txtStatus.Text += e.Name + " E#" + e.ErrorCode.ToString();
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void MyVariable_ValueChanged(object sender, VariableEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myStructPV == null) //PG35 stuff may need to move
            {
                myStructPV = new Variable(myTask, "Pv_Struct");
                myStructPV.Active = true;
                myStructPV.RefreshTime = 1000;
                myStructPV.ValueChanged += MyStructPV_ValueChanged;
                myStructPV.Error += MyStructPV_Error;
                myStructPV.Connect();
            }
            // /\ above may need to be moved back.
            if (e.Name == "Lifesign")
            {
                lblValLifesign.Text = ((Variable)sender).Value.ToString();
            }
            if (e.Name == "linkVarPV1")
            {
                lblPV1.Text = ((Variable)sender).Value.ToString();
            }
            Variable tmpVar = (Variable)sender; //PG 36 - 37

            if(e.Name == "Pv_Struct")
            {
                if (tmpVar.Value.DataType == DataType.Structure)
                {
                    foreach (Variable member in tmpVar.Members.Values)
                    {
                        txtStatus.Text += member.Value.ToString() + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (String membername in e.ChangedMembers)
            {
                if (membername != null)
                {
                    txtStatus.Text += tmpVar.Value[membername].ToString() + "\r\n";

                }
            }
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void CmdConnectPV1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Variable myLinkPV1 = new Variable(myVariable, "linkVarPV1");
            myLinkPV1.LinkName = myVariablePV1.FullName;
            myLinkPV1.Active = true;
            myLinkPV1.ValueChanged += MyLinkPV1_ValueChanged;
            myLinkPV1.Error += MyLinkPV1_Error;
            myLinkPV1.Connect(ConnectionType.Link);
        }

        private void MyLinkPV1_Error(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void MyLinkPV1_ValueChanged(object sender, VariableEventArgs e)
        {
           // throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void CmdReadVar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myVariable.ValueRead += MyVariable_ValueRead;
            myVariable.ReadValue();
        }

        private void MyVariable_ValueRead(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblReadVar.Text = ((Variable)sender).Value.ToString();
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void CmdReadTime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myCpu.DateTimeRead += MyCpu_DateTimeRead;
            myCpu.ReadDateTime();
        }

        private void MyCpu_DateTimeRead(object sender, CpuEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dt;
            dt = e.DateTime;
            this.Text = dt.ToString();
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void CmdWriteVal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myVariable.Value = 0;
            myVariable.ValueWritten += MyVariable_ValueWritten;
        }

        private void MyVariable_ValueWritten(object sender, PviEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void CmdSetStruct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myStructPV.WriteValueAutomatic = false;
            myStructPV.Value["Member1"] = 10;
            myStructPV.Value["Member2"] = 20;
            myStructPV.Value["Member3"] = myVariable.Value;
            myStructPV.WriteValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @SandyOne, welcome to SO. This "PVI" thing you talk about... what is it? Is this some proprietary SDK for a product? It seems that your question is quite specific to these libraries and I am afraid that it would be really difficult to answer. From the code, It would seem that `CmdSetStruct_Click()` would always fail with `myStructPV` being `null` if `MyVariable_ValueChanged()` has not been called first.

Comment: Hi @istepaniuk PVI stands for Process Visualization Interface. Basically the Program automation studio which is used to write the software for a B&R PLC uses PVI to transfer the written software to the PLC as well as handling a lot of other data such as the variables. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: The training manual is dated because using PVI is dated. You should probably be using OPC UA or Modbus for this (nModbus4 is a great library for that). However, PVI does have the benefit of showing you all the variables on the PLC and giving you access to them without having to do anything with the PLC code.

It sounds like you have the PVI comms working, you just don't have variables with the names used in the C# code actually on your PLC. Your status text gets all the way to `Task pvitest Connected`?

Comment: Thanks Isaac i really appreciate the feedback. I am not sure how to go about using OPC UA or Modbus ill have a look into it. In regards to Task pvitest connecting that does happen but i have trouble creating a consistent connection (i get it to connect sometimes and other times not at all no matter what i try.) I think it may have to do with the fact that my pvi license runs on trial mode?

Answer (score 1):

`myStructPV` is null because you're calling `CmdSetStruct_Click()` without having created `myStructPV`. You'd need `MyVariable_ValueChanged()` to run first or to at least put the code from it that creates `myStructPV` into `CmdSetStruct_Click()`.

As long as you are getting to status "Task pvitest Connected" when running the init stuff, then all the PVI connection is working (if you don't have a task on you PLC named `pvitest` but still make it to `CPU Connected` then you're doing okay still). You just have to debug your connecting to actual tags.

As far as communicating with an existing Windows program written by the OEM, that's unlikely. You'd have to use some kind of debugger to get at its memory or hope they made some kind of API which is very unlikely.

Comment: Thank you very much for this I will definitely try this. For the sake of checking if it works I will try but as you mentioned communicating with the Windows program that was created by the OEM is unlikely. I do have the program which they created previously to do exactly this but due to a change in the OS they are using on the PC running this software it will no longer run on that PC. Im not able to decompile any of the two programs that they have made so i cant really see how they have done this. However thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think Isaac is right to assume that you click on the button that executes`CmdSetStruct_Click()` before you actually initialize the myStruct Pv. 
This could be because your connection to the PLC doesn't work up until to the point where you are able to get the `valueChanged` event from the Lifebit variable.

Could your Lifebit variable on the PLC be global? Would be nice to see the console output of the VS to be able to pinpoint the issue until it crashes.

Regarding running in the PVI trial mode you are right, it can create some problems for the initial connection but in that case, if you just stop the PVI manager and start it again, it should all be fine.

I'd anyway recommend you to have just one struct for handling the communication in an out of the PLC. For example:

```
gComm.ToPlc.Status.someVariable
gComm.FromPlc.Cmd.startDoingSth
```

With that, you would have to go through the PVI variable connection process twice only. Once to connect to the ToPlc struct and once to connect to the FromPlc struct. Your code will be a lot easier to manage that way.

And finally, you can use the `onConnected` events of the variables rather than the `valueChanged`. That way before you allow your app to move on, you can wait until you get a valid connection on the variables & catch the errors thrown from the variable connection and handle them gracefully. This would make it possible to prevent your app from crashing.